# What name should i give for a ipad background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Im creating a universal app. in my login page i am having a background image i named it as `LoginBG@2x` and `LoginBG@3x` for iphone-4,5 and iphone-6 respectively. So, what name should i give for the ipad version images so that iOS will automatically pick them up when my app is viewed in iPad

Answer (score 2):

Use Image `Asset Catalogs` instead. 
It manages image according to device.

You can drag and drop images in respective position -

[image]

For more information read - [Asset Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can give the name as :

> file~ipad.png
>
> file@2x~ipad.png

Or batter you can use the [assets catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yo can give name like easily you can remember.

like

abc.png
abc_ipad.png